# How is a For-Loop different from a List Comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I did try understanding and looking for answers online but I couldn't find a **clear** and **simple** explanation of how a for-loop is different from a list comprehension. Here is an example that I thought would return the same thing, but it didn't.

Given a set of numbers, return the inverse of each element. Each positive becomes negative, and the negative become positive.

```
a_list = [1, 2, -3, 4, 5]
```

a for-loop

```
def invert(a_list):
    for x in a_list:
        return -x

invert(a_list)
-1
```

whereas in a list comprehension...

```
def invert(a_list):
    return [-x for x in a_list]

invert(a_list)
[-1, -2, 3, -4, -5]
```

I appreciate any explanation, I am still a bit confused as to when to use one or the other.
Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with for loop vs list comp, it's all about messing up the for loop code.

Comment: A for loop does more than comprehend a list and a list comprehension is **not** a one line for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ a for loop is a general purpose loop method, you can do anything inside your loop, and it can contain many lines of code.
calculus,
printing,
calling other functions ...

2/ a list comprehension goal is to generate a list object,
it is usually a one liner, and used to make it nice and short to write and read

3/ in your example, you do not really loop, as your return the first iteration value: -x
you do not allow the second iteration to append

if you want exactly the same behavior:

```
a_list = [1, 2, -3, 4, 5]
inverted = [-x for x in a_list]
print(inverted)
```

does the same and same result as:

```
a_list = [1, 2, -3, 4, 5]
inverted = []
for x in a_list:
    inverted.append(-x)
print(inverted)
```

Benefit: the list comprehension here is shorter to write, as this list is easy/short to write.So both methods works here, but it is more pythonic and nice to write it as a list comprehension when you can do it.

Comment: Thank you. I am sure that everyone learning Python will appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions do not do the same thing. In the first example you return before iterating through the loop so only one item is returned.  The second example returns the full new list.

You'd need to do something more like this:

```
a_list = [1, 2, -3, 4, 5]

def invert_one(a_list):
    invert_list = []
    for x in a_list:
        invert_list.append(-x)
    return invert_list

def invert_two(a_list):
    return [-x for x in a_list]

print(invert_one(a_list))
[-1, -2, 3, -4, -5]

print(invert_two(a_list))
[-1, -2, 3, -4, -5]
```